# Cast drops Implemented Member array in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

Consider:

```
class Order
{
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems {get;set;}
}

class SalesOrder : Order
{
    public List<SalesOrderItem> OrderItems {get;set;}
}

class OrderItem {}

class SalesOrderItem : OrderItem {}
```

When trying to cast

```
SalesOrder salesorder = new SalesOrder();
salesorder.OrderItems = List<SalesOrderItem>();
salesorder.OrderItems.Add(new SalesOrderItem());
Order order = salesorder;
```

`order.Orderitems` is null. Is there any way I get get this cast to work with derived properties?

I have tried covariance with an interface, but then cannot use `List` and using `IEnumerable` will not allow for a public setter. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: That won't compile - seems that you're missing a `new` on the `OrderItems` property in `SalesOrder`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, i do not think this is a dupe. OP probably just did not show the property initialization code. The question seems to be about `OrderItems` inheritance, it has nothing to do with NRE

Comment: The problem here is that the compiler does not treat both versions of OrderItems as the same thing. Inheritance doesn't work that way.  Even with new, the cast will still not work the way you want.

Comment: @ChrisMantle It's a compiler warning, not an error. Should be an error IMO - it should force you to acknowledge that you're really doing `new`.

Comment: I'd have something like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtvDBB

Comment: @JoeEnos Indeed - I've always got warnings as errors on, forgot it was just a warning :)

Comment: Franklin, please confirm my edit is in line of what you are doing - I've added `salesorder.OrderItems = List<SalesOrderItem>();` that removes NRE on Add call and makes it clear that `SalesOrder.OrderItems` is not `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. It looks like you are confusing some OO concepts, and the way they are implemented in C#.

In your code you are trying to derive `SalesOrder` from `Order`. This is the most important mistake: it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In particular, it means that a derived class may not add additional contraints to the signatures of its members. Note that your `SalesOrder` class *does* add such a constraint: the order items must be of type `SalesOrderItem`, while the `Order` class accepts all order items derived from `OrderItem`.

What you want instead is specialization: the `SalesOrder` class is more strict than just the `Order` class: it can only contain SalesOrderItems. Specialization is achieved by using generics. So you could define your classes as follows:

```
public class Order<T> where T: OrderItem
{
    public List<T> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
}

public class SalesOrder : Order<SalesOrderItem>
{
}

public class SalesOrderItem : OrderItem
{
}
```

**Update**: to illustrate why it is impossible to cast `SalesOrder` to `Order<OrderItem>`, consider the following static method:

```
public static void AddOrderItem(Order<OrderItem> order)
{
    var item = new OrderItem();
    order.OrderItems.Add(order);
}
```

If `SalesOrder` were derived from `Order<OrderItem>`, you would be able to write this:

```
var order = new SalesOrder();
AddOrderItem(order);
```

However, this would result in a type error, since SalesOrder can't contain an ordinary OrderItem. Now, if the only reason for you to cast a `SalesOrder` to an `Order` is to *read* the orderitems, you could introduce an interface instead:

```
public interface IOrder
{
    IEnumerable<OrderItem> GetItems();
}

public class Order<T> : IOrder where T: OrderItem
{
    public List<T> OrderItems { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OrderItem> GetItems()
    {
        return this.OrderItems;
    }
}
```

Now you can cast your `SalesOrder` object to `IOrder` and read the order items.

Comment: This is the exact solution I had before I tried the one in the question. I still cannot cast SalesOrder to Order<OrderItem> - Also you are right thanks for pointing out my Liskov violation

Answer (score 5):

This is what's known as "[shadowing](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Interviews/answer/3623/what-is-shadowing-in-C-Sharp)".

Your `salesOrder` has two `OrderItems` properties - one that's only visible to `SalesOrder`s, and one that's only visible to `Order`s. The `OrderItems` property in the child class is hiding the one in the parent class. You are adding an item to one, and then observing the other.

I think you need to rethink your design, but you can resolve this issue one way by removing the property from the child class:

```
class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems {get;set;}
}

class SalesOrder : Order { }

class OrderItem {}

class SalesOrderItem : OrderItem {}
```

Another option is to make `Order` a generic class:

```
class Order<T> where T: OrderItem
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> OrderItems {get;set;}
}

class SalesOrder : Order<SalesOrderItem> { }

class OrderItem {}

class SalesOrderItem : OrderItem {}
```

```
SalesOrder salesorder = new SalesOrder();
salesorder.OrderItems.Add(new SalesOrderItem());
Order<SalesOrderItem> order = salesorder;
```

The benefit of the second approach is that it allows `OrderItems` to store a specific type of order item rather than the most general type.

Comment: Note: this makes items in `SalesOrder.OrderItems` to have type `OrderItem` so you'll have to case them to `SalesOrderItem`.

Comment: The last line needs to read Order<OrderItem> order = salesorder;  I tried this solution and C# compiler will not cast that

Comment: @Franklin Yes, there's a very good reason for that. If you want to get all the `OrderItem`s in a `SalesOrder`, you can do `IEnumerable<OrderItem> orderItems = salesOrder.OrderItems.Cast<OrderItem>();`, but you can't cast an `Order<SalesOrderItem>` to `Order<OrderItem>`. It would violate the type system. It's for the same reason that you can't cast a `List<SalesOrderItem>` to a `List<OrderItem>`.

Comment: Looks like I will use the 2nd example and write some mapping code to do the pseudo 'casting'